# Question about showing $R^{*}/N\cong R^{**}$

Tags: group-theory

For the following question:

Let $R^{*}$ be the multiplicative group of nonzero real numbers and let $N$ be the subgroup $\{1,-1\}$.  Prove that $R^{*}/N$ is isomorphic to the multiplicative group $R^{**}$ of positive numbers.

I need to write an explicit map from $R^{*}/N$ to $R^{**}$.  $\textbf{Can I let}$ $f(Nx)=\lvert x\rvert$ from the beginning instead of $f(\lvert x\rvert)=Nx$. The student solutions manual first write the function:  $f(x)=Nx$, then the absolute value of x is used when it justifies that $f$ is surjective:

> For any $x\in R^{*},$ the absolute value $\lvert x\rvert$ is in $R^{**}$.  Also $\lvert x\rvert\in Nx$ so that $f(\lvert x\rvert)=Nx.$

Thank you in advance

Comment: If you define a map out of $R^*/N$ by specifying where it maps cosets, you need to check that such a map is well-defined. Another approach would be to define a map $f:R^*\to R^{**}$ and show that $\ker f=N$ and that $f$ is surjective.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow if I define a map $f:R^{*}\rightarrow R^{**}$, then would the function be simply be $f(x)=\lvert x \rvert$?

Comment: Yep, now compute the kernel of that map.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow if I define a map $f$ from $R^{**}$ to $R^{*}/N$, I can make use of the isomorphism theorems, where as if I define $f$ from  $R^{*}/N$ to $R^{**}$ instead, I just need to show homomorphism, and bijection for showing isomorphism.  Does this apply to general situation?  The reason I ask this are for two reasons.  I am at the chapter of the text where quotient groups are discussed, but isomorphism and homomorphism are discussed in the next section.  So any questions related to isomorphisms, the standard isomorphism theorems can't be used yet.  Second is, when...

Comment: @MichaelMorrow ...I was learning rings, sometimes, I see isomorphism theorems, to use this question as an example, I can see maps using $f$ mapping from $R^{**}$ to $R^{*}/N$ or $f$ from  $R^{*}/N$ to $R^{**}$ when talking about isomorphism theorems for rings.

Comment: Use `$\Bbb R$` for $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $\textbf{Can I let}$ $f(Nx)=\lvert x\rvert$ from the beginning instead of $f(\lvert x\rvert)=Nx$.

Yes, as long as you check the due things, *accordingly*. Moreover, everything can be done even prior to letting kernel concept setting in (let alone the homomorphism theorems), which, IMHO, tends here to hastily sell off the basics.

So, if you address the (tentative) map $f\colon \Bbb R^*/N\longrightarrow\Bbb R^*_{>0}$, defined by $f(Nx):=|x|$, then you first have to check whether this is well-defined, as $f$'s definition depends on the choice of coset's representative. But $Nx=\{x,-x\}$, so $f(N(-x))=\left|-x\right|=|x|=f(Nx)$, and you are done. Next, $f(NxNy)=f(Nxy)=|xy|=|x||y|=f(Nx)f(Ny)$ (operation-preserving). Surjectivity is plain, because every positive real number $y$ is the modulus of itself, and hence $\Bbb R^*_{>0}\ni y=|y|=f(Ny)$. Injectivity: $f(Ny)=f(Nx)\Longrightarrow |y|=|x|\Longrightarrow y=\pm x\Longrightarrow y\in Nx\Longrightarrow Ny=Nx$.

On the other hand, if you address the (tentative) map $\hat f\colon \Bbb R^*_{>0}\longrightarrow \Bbb R^*/N$, defined by $f(x):=Nx$, then good-definiteness is not in the agenda, as there's no arbitrary choice in the definition of $\hat f$. Next, $\hat f(xy)=Nxy=NxNy=\hat f(x)\hat f(y)$ (operation-preserving). Surjectivity: since $Nx=N(-x)$, either $Nx=\hat f(x)$ or $Nx=\hat f(-x)$, according to which one is positive between $x$ and $-x$. Injectivity: $\hat f(y)=\hat f(x)\Longrightarrow Ny=Nx\Longrightarrow y=\pm x\Longrightarrow y=x$ (as $x,y$ are both positive).

Therefore, $\Bbb R^*/N\stackrel{f}{\cong}\Bbb R^*_{>0}$ or, equivalently, $\Bbb R^*_{>0} \stackrel{\hat f}{\cong}\Bbb R^*/N$.

Comment: sorry for the late reply.  I just have a quick question for your detailed answer write up.  When you say "..because every positive real number  is the modulus of itself".  What do the phrase mean when you say a number is the modulus of itself?  Did you mean absolute value or did you mean it in terms of congruence arithmetic?

Comment: @SethMai, I mean the absolute value: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value